# How do i install Rundeck's Docker Plugin

Tags: docker, rundeck

I'm trying to manage scheduled jobs (in a Docker image) via Rundeck. I found out that Rundeck has official Docker plugins. However, i couldn't find the instructions to install them.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiezNnXYBH4) on how to use the plugins, but missing the installation part.

I'm running Rundeck 3.1 on Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the official image. I leave the following [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) that adds the docker plugin (the file name is "Dockerfile" too):

```
# OFFICIAL RUNDECK DOCKER IMAGE :-)
FROM rundeck/rundeck:3.2.0

# BUILD INFO
MAINTAINER MegaDrive68k <somebody@example.net>

# ENVIRONMENT PARAMS
ENV RDECK_BASE=/home/rundeck

# ADD THE DOCKER PLUGIN (IN FACT, YOU CAN ADD ANYTHING IF YOU WANT)
COPY docker-container-1.4.1.zip ${RDECK_BASE}/libext
```

Just save this file (remember that the file name is "Dockerfile") and put the [plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/docker/releases) (zip file) in the same directory, then you need to build it:

```
docker build -t megadrive/rundeckcustom:1.0 .
```

And now you can run it with:

```
docker run -p 4440:4440 megadrive/rundeckcustom:1.0
```

Comment: I didnt notice the releases. The plugin README mentioned about compiling yourself using gradle. But it never mentioned about installation process. I cant even find in official docs. Let me try this and feedback.