# Can we have more than one installation of Rundeck in a Linux server?

Tags: installation, rundeck

I have one installation of Rundeck in a Linux server and it is up & running on port 4440. But I want to have one more installation of it and expecting it to run on other port. Is it possible? This question may look weird but I want to have additional setup of Rundeck due to personal reasons.

Eagerly looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your "Personal instance" with a docker container without touch the "real instance" (or use two docker containers if you want), in both cases, you need to specify different ports (for example 4440 for "real" instance/container and 5550 to "test" container).

[Here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck/) you have the official docker image, [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/docker.html) about how to run, check the "Environment variables" section to specify the TCP port of each container (also, you have a lot of params to test).
And [here](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo) you have a lot of configurations to test (LDAP, DB backends, etc..).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Finally I am able to host Rundeck in Docker. But how to persist my changes in rundeck-config.properties file in the same container? For every small change in rundeck-config.properties, creating a new docker image is looking like a big problem.

Comment: Hi! You can use docker cp for that, take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/ or create your "custom rundeck container" and copy the file with custom config later, more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466889/how-do-i-install-rundecks-docker-plugin

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the update. From my exploration, I was able to mount the config folder in my host folder. So it is easy for me now to update the required config in my host folder. And I am able to see the updated configuration in the container. But when I check the configuration in the Rundeck web UI, my changes are not reflecting there? I am seeing default config settings only. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rundeck with Docker you must change the init.sh.

He is responsible of configuration overwrite at each container creation, so all your configuration updates are lost.

Doing this also avoid to have clear configuration params i' your docker-compose file...

The steps are :

- create docker-compose file as mentioned on Rundeck Docker hub
- map volumes on your host so you can save rundeck's files and directory
- stop your container
- comment config overwrite in init.sh
- restart your container

You can then update rundeck's config on the fly and just restart rundeck container to see the changes...